# Ruby Object Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, inheritance

In Ruby I want to implement a class Person so that each instance of this class can have children and grandchildren (of that same class Person) - but not beyond grandchildren.

Comment: You need to be more specific, is this just a regular class or are these active record models?

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII regular class

Comment: If `i1` and `i2` are instances of `Person`, what does it mean that `i2` is a child or grandchild of `i1`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need inheritance, the concept is that the subsequent classes are not of the same class, they share a lot of core behavior but are significantly different. All you have described is a contextual different with relation to each other not an actual difference in behavior.

```
class Person
  def children
    @children ||= []
  end

  def grand_children
    @grand_children ||= []
  end
end

guy = Person.new
son = Person.new
grandson = Person.new
guy.children << son
guy.grand_children << grandson
```